# Google map inflate exception

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to use Google map into `fragment` on Android 4.4.2(19 API)
On API 20+ it works fine but on 19 API I have this exception:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error
>   inflating class fragment

**fragment_map.xml:**

```
     ...
   <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            ...
```

**MapFragment.java**

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);//this row have error on Api 19
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
//        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
//                .findFragmentById(R.id.map); //it's not work on 19 API

        setupListeners();
        return view;
    }
```

**manifest:**

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

**gradle:**

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
```

**full error:**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: ru.company.getpizza, PID: 10968
>                     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                         at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                         at ru.copmany.getpizza.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:119)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:164)
>                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
>                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
>                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17040)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5395)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17040)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:926)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17040)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5395)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17040)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5395)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17040)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5395)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17040)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5395)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17040)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5395)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2473)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17040)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2412)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1380)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1651)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1257)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6424)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventRe

Comment: You try to inflate one fragment into another via XMl. It's impossible. Nested fragments can be done only programmatically [docs  here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

Comment: @nnesterov ok. but why it working on 20+ API?

Comment: Not sure why does it work in 21+ api. Anyway, official docs say that it isn't supported. Your fragment that is used only for include other fragment seems redundant. Why don't you inflate `SupportMapFragment` directly in your activity or inflate `MapView` in your fragment?